# What software is available for program 'workflow' visualization?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, visualization

I'd like to create a flowchart/map visualization of how my project works, what is the best software available for this purpose?  I'm not looking for something to do it automatically, I'd like to manually create the flowchart.

This is for a project done in Objective-C if that helps/matters.

Comment: There are lots of programs available flowcharting / diagramming. In the past I've used Dia, and Visio is another popular option.

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion to use Dia (which does look great) had a link leading to gliffy which is I think what I'll ultimately use.

Comment: Consider using a Sankey diagram. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60954545/1430996

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) is pretty good. It even creates class diagrams from an Xcode 3.x project.

Comment: Damn, I totally forgot about OmniGraffle!  Downloading a demo of that too.

Answer (score 5):

Other web applications that do this, that are not already mentioned:

[draw.io](https://www.draw.io), is free and uses Google Drive or Dropbox for storage (including Google Drive Realtime). I co-founded this.

[Lucidchart](http://www.lucidchart.com/) is native JavaScript, like draw.io.

[Creately](http://creately.com/) and [Cacoo](http://www.cacoo.com/) are Flash implementations, although Cacoo are moving away from Flash.

Aside from my obvious bias, I would suggest Lucidchart or [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/) (mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

If you (a) like gliffy and (b) want a desktop-based app that does the same thing, take a look at [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html).  Supports BPMN and traditional flowcharts (as well as myriad other drawing notations).  Nice and easy to use, cross-platform.  Oh, and free :-)

hth.